# matlab: finding indices of values common for two matrices

Tags: arrays, matlab, find, compare, indices

I have a simple question.

lets say we have two arrays:

```
data = [1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 6];
A = [1 3 6];
```

I want to have indices of values from data which are equal to any value from A.

i.e. answer for that will be: 1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 19, 20, 21

How to do it without using for loop and scanning each value from A one by one..?
Thanks!
Art.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will do exactly that:

```
inds = find(ismember(data, A))
```

the function `ismember` will find all elements in `data` that are in `A`. The second output of `ismember` could also be useful:

```
>> [~, b] = ismember(data, A))
ans = 
    1 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3
```

where the `1`, `2` and `3` refer to the index into `A`.